# How to create a race in setters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have setters:

```
addSettersAndGetters(i) {
  // Vue component
  const self = this;
  let promise_h, promise_w;
  Object.defineProperties(this.preorder_positions[i].shapes[0].shape, {
      'height_out': {
        set: function (val) {
          this._height_out = +val;
          self.preorder_positions[i].height = +val;
          promise_h = new Promise (() => self.validateShapes(i));
        },
        get: function () {
          return this._height_out;
        }
      },
      'width_out': {
        set: function (val) {
          this._width_out = +val;
          self.preorder_positions[i].width = +val;
          promise_w = new Promise (() => self.validateShapes(i));
        },
        get: function () {
          return this._width_out;
        }
      },
    });

    return Promise.race([promise_h, promise_w]);
  },
```

But when I call the method, the error is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function

How can I implement a race, as this will reduce the number of database queries?

> UPD: Function call - `this.addSettersAndGetters(i)`

```
  validateShapes(pi) {
    // validateShapes запускается в updated без pi
    if (pi !== undefined ) {
      const self = this;
      let promise = new Promise(function () {
        self.$refs.form.validate();
      });
      promise.then(self.getPositionPrice(pi));
      this.first_validation = true;
    }
  },
```

Comment: `self.validateShapes(i)` does not return a function? Also `promise_h` and `promise_w` will be undefined by the time you call `Promise.race`, also `Promise.race` expects an array.

Comment: That error indicates you're not passing a function into `new Promise(`. Can you show us what validateShapes is doing?

Comment: @JonasWilms what could be the solution?

Comment: `validateShapes` does not return anything. But I'm still not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @JonasWilms Edited the question. Did so. `(() => this.validateShapes ())`. No errors. But the race either. It is necessary that the function `validateShapes` be executed 1 time.